# Reverse M2M query in Django-template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to fetch the names of the speakers in the template. I marked it with xxxx. How can I do this? Thank you so much for helping out. My files:

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Speaker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    cities = City.objects.all().exclude(speaker__isnull=True)
    return render(request, "index.html", {"cities":cities})
```

index.html

```
{% for i in cities %}
{{ i.name }},xxx{{ i.speaker.name }}xxx<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the speakers for each city as `speaker_set`:

```
{% for cit in cities %}
   {{ cit.name }}
   {% for spkr in cit.speaker_set.all %}
      {{ spkr.name }}
   <br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```